# Mysqli Query result to variable

Tags: php, html

I was trying to make a MySQL word with PHP, and I want to call the result into the next page using session. So I can put the result in the ms word file, but the value in `"$_SESSION['kode_faskes'] = $d['kode_faskes'];"` was stated as `null`.

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on the value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php on line 80

this is the code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="index.php" method="get">
  <label> Cari :</label>
  <input type="text" name="cari">
  <input type="submit" value="cari">
 </form>
 <?php
 //search norek 
 if(isset($_GET['cari']))
 {
  $cari = $_GET['cari'];
  echo "<b>Hasil Pencarian : ".$cari."</b>";
 }
 ?>
  <table width="600" border="1">
   <?php
   if(isset($_GET['cari']))
   {
    $cari = $_GET['cari'];
    $dato = mysqli_query($connect, "
SELECT
 * 
FROM
 faskes
 INNER JOIN pemilik_rekening USING ( norek )
 INNER JOIN transaksi USING ( kode_faskes )
WHERE transaksi.norek LIKE
'%".$cari."%'
");
   } else {
    $dato = mysqli_query($connect, "
SELECT
 * 
FROM
 faskes
 INNER JOIN pemilik_rekening USING ( norek )
 INNER JOIN transaksi USING ( kode_faskes )
 ");
   }
   $no = 1;
 while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($dato))
 {
   ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['kode_faskes']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['nama_faskes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['alamat_faskes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['norek']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['pemegang_norek']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['tanggal_bayar']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $d['jumlah_bayar']; ?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php }   
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['cari'] = $cari;
   $_SESSION['kode_faskes'] = $d['kode_faskes'];
 ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can help me then I would be grateful for this.

In addition, I'm deeply sorry about the short explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session_start()` function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

```js
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

        <form action="index.php" method="get">
        <label> Cari :</label>
        <input type="text" name="cari">
        <input type="submit" value="cari">
    </form>
    <?php
    //search norek 
    if(isset($_GET['cari']))
    {
        $cari = $_GET['cari'];
        echo "<b>Hasil Pencarian : ".$cari."</b>";
    }
    ?>
        <table width="600" border="1">
      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['cari']))
      {
          $cari = $_GET['cari'];
          $dato = mysqli_query($connect, "
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    faskes
    INNER JOIN pemilik_rekening USING ( norek )
    INNER JOIN transaksi USING ( kode_faskes )
WHERE transaksi.norek LIKE
'%".$cari."%'
");
      } else {
          $dato = mysqli_query($connect, "
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    faskes
    INNER JOIN pemilik_rekening USING ( norek )
    INNER JOIN transaksi USING ( kode_faskes )
    ");
      }
      $no = 1;
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($dato))
    {
      ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['kode_faskes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['nama_faskes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['alamat_faskes']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['norek']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['pemegang_norek']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['tanggal_bayar']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d['jumlah_bayar']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php     
      $_SESSION['cari'] = $cari;
      $_SESSION['kode_faskes'] = $d['kode_faskes'];
    }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```